# how to create the same directory name inside every sub-directory with linux bash

Tags: bash, directory

let's suppose I have a directory structure and I want to create a directory called `new` inside each subdirectory recursively.

For instance, If I have

```
dir1
  |
  -------dir11
  |
  -------dir12
           |
           ------dir121
dir2
```

I want to create `new` directories like this:

```
 dir1
  |
  -------dir11
  |        |
  |        -------new
  |
  -------dir12
  |        |
  |        ------dir121
  |        |        |
  |        |        ---------new
  |        |
  |        ------new
  |
  -------new

dir2
  |
  -------new
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type d ! -name "*new*" -exec mkdir {}/new \;
```

find all folders. make a folder in that folder called new. don't make folders in folders that have `new` in the same (otherwise it'll get dir1/new/new/new/new, etc)

Comment: didn't worked. I tried and created `./dir1/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/new/...`. Has to stop it

Comment: and there were no folders called new